# Graduate Research Fellowship Program (GRFP) 2nd Year Graduate Student Eligibility

Tags: nsf

I am a bit confused about the Graduate Research Fellowship Program (GRFP) academic level requirements. There seems to be a contradiction. The application implies second year graduate students can apply, but also says that no more than one academic year of graduate study should be completed. Either that or I am not familiar with the academic meaning of the terms **"2nd year grad student"** or/and **"one academic year of graduate study"**.

I am a second year graduate student. I started in Fall of 2020, and have completed three full-time semesters : (1) Fall 2019, (2) Spring 2020, and (3) Summer of 2020. Does this mean I am not eligible to apply?

https://www.nsf.gov/pubs/2016/nsf16588/nsf16588.htm

> As a general rule, applicants must not have completed more than 12
> months of full-time graduate study or its equivalent as defined by the
> universities attended as of August 1 of the year the GRFP application
> is submitted.

#### Academic Level: Only one level can apply

**Level 1: Undergrad/Bachelor's**
Current Senior, or completed Bachelor's degree; never enrolled in graduate degree program, ready to enroll full-time by Fall 2021.

**Level 2: 1st year grad student**
Current first year graduate student in eligible Field of Study at US academic institution. Currently enrolled in joint Bachelor's-Master's degree (must have completed three academic years in program).

**Level 3: 2nd year grad student**
No more than one academic year of graduate study in eligible Field of Study at US academic institution. Joint Bachelor's-Master's degree holders who progressed to a doctoral program the semester following award of joint degree (summer break acceptable), who have not applied previously as graduate students, may apply as first-year doctoral students only.

**Level 4: Returning grad student**
NOT enrolled in graduate school. Two-years post Master's degree. No terminal (doctoral) degree holders.

Comment: Is summer 2020 an official part of your program? E.g. taking classes?

Comment: You started in Fall 2020, but you completed three semesters including Fall 2019?  Is there a typo?

Comment: @NateEldredge That's a bummer, but makes perfect sense! There's already other opportunities.

Comment: No wait, I read it wrong.  New comment coming...

Comment: You would be submitting in October 2020, correct?  And as of August 1, 2020, you had only completed 12 months of graduate study or less (since you started in Fall 2019).  So you meet the criteria for Level 3.  Moreover, you will be in your second year when you submit the application in October, so that checks out too.  It seems clearly based on actual time in the program, not number of semesters.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I will be applying in October 2020. That makes more sense. You are correct, I will **not** have completed **over** 12 months of study. Indeed I have completed exactly 12 months of study, so I am eligible. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry about my earlier comment.  I was remembering old rules from years ago, and also I incorrectly thought the upcoming application deadline would be something like January 2021, which would mean that eligibility would be based on number of years completed by August 1, 2021.  Anyway, it's not so.